# use redis and mongo alongside postgres in docker

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, redis

I am learning to use docker in one of my project which has the following tech stack

django

redis

mysql - production

sqlite - development

mongod

I could configure a simple docker which covers django related and mysql but have no idea how to glue redis and mongod as well. I see various ways in internet but based on the configuration i already made how should i fit them well.

Here is what I have done

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/python/Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "sleep 3; python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile

```
# python image (https://hub.docker.com/_/python/)
FROM python:3.6

# Environment Variables
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1


COPY ./requirements/requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt


RUN chmod ug+x /code/initialize.sh

COPY . /code/

WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 8000
```

**initialize.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script initializes the Django project. It will be executed (from
# supervisord) every time the Docker image is run.

# If we're not in production, create a temporary dev database
if [ "$DJANGO_PRODUCTION" != "true" ]; then
    echo "DJANGO_PRODUCTION=false; creating local database..."
    # Wait until the MySQL daemon is running
    while [ "$(pgrep mysql | wc -l)" -eq 0 ] ; do
        echo "MySQL daemon not running; waiting one second..."
        sleep 1
    done
    # Wait until we can successfully connect to the MySQL daemon
    until mysql -uroot -pdevrootpass -e ";" ; do
        echo "Can't connect to MySQL; waiting one second..."
        sleep 1
    done
    echo "MySQL daemon is running; creating database..."
    mysql -uroot -e "CREATE DATABASE appDB; CREATE USER milan@localhost; SET PASSWORD FOR milan@localhost=PASSWORD('milan'); GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON appDB.* TO milan@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'milan'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" -pdevrootpass;
else
    echo "DJANGO_PRODUCTION=true; no local database created"
fi

# Initialize Django project
python /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python /code/manage.py makemigrations
python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput

# Create a Django superuser named `root` if it doesn't yet exist
echo "Creating Django superuser named 'root'..."
if [ "$DJANGO_PRODUCTION" != "true" ]; then
    # We're in the dev environment
    if [ "$ROOT_PASSWORD" == "" ]; then
        # Root password environment variable is not set; so, load it from config.ini
        echo "from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser; parser = SafeConfigParser(); parser.read('/code/config.ini'); from django.contrib.auth.models import User; print 'Root user already exists' if User.objects.filter(username='root') else User.objects.create_superuser('root', 'admin@example.com', parser.get('general', 'ROOT_PASSWORD'))" | python /code/manage.py shell
    else
        # Root password environment variable is set; so, use it
        echo "import os; from django.contrib.auth.models import User; print 'Root user already exists' if User.objects.filter(username='root') else User.objects.create_superuser('root', 'admin@example.com', os.environ['ROOT_PASSWORD'])" | python /code/manage.py shell
    fi
else
    # We're in production; use root password environment variable
    echo "import os; from django.contrib.auth.models import User; print 'Root user already exists' if User.objects.filter(username='root') else User.objects.create_superuser('root', 'admin@example.com', os.environ['ROOT_PASSWORD'])" | python /code/manage.py shell
fi
```

so my question is how do i glue redis and mongo here?

P.S please let me know if I am out of best practice way.

Answer (score 0):

the most common practice is having one process per container, i.e add redis and mongo to the docker-file

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/python/Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "sleep 3; python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  redis:
    image: "redis:2.8"

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
```

regarding sqlite, you can use shared volume with the computer / instance for the db file itself.

Comment: You have only pulled the image for redis and mongod. Don't i need to define the command for running redis-server and mongod?

Comment: you are wrong, redis and mongo Dockerfiles contains CMD layers that start the processes. try it before you comment